# Ubuntu: how do you swap eth0 and eth1? (Ubuntu 13.10 server in a VirtualBox VM)

Tags: ubuntu, networking, virtualbox

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 server (64-bit) in a VirtualBox 4.3.6 VM (Windows host) with one NAT adapter assigned. The only non-default software selected during installation was OpenSSH. So far so good... I could ping the world and the address is 10.0.2.15 as would be expected (per ifconfig the NAT adapter is eth0 at this point).

I want to access the VM via the host without any port-mapping. Since bridging isn't an option (I can't get a second direct IP from outside the host) I created a host-only adapter (with DHCP enabled and all), edited /etc/network/interfaces (duplicating the eth0 defaults for eth1), shut the VM down, attached the new host-only adapter (selected paravirtualized), and rebooted.

At this point /etc/network/interfaces contained the following:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

And indeed it all works... but per ifconfig the NAT adapter is now eth1, while the newly-added host-only adapter is eth0. I want it the other way around - and that leads to all kinds of problems!

First I tried adding the MAC addresses to the interfaces file, e.g., "hwaddress ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx" as I expect it to be for eth0 and eth1. No joy... that ends up breaking networking entirely. I commented out those lines and rebooted (I actually had to disable that host-only adapter and reboot again, then I could finally re-enable it... this may be a clue.)

Reading further, I see many references to updating /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules to swap the MAC addresses. Great idea! Except that *other than a README file /etc/udev/rules.d is completely empty.* I tried "sudo udevadm trigger" (and a few permutations thereof)... no change.

**So question #1: what happened to 70-persistent-net.rules? Is that deprecated? /etc/udev/rules.d is empty except for a README file.**

Next, I tried the following:

sudo ifconfig eth0 down
sudo ifconfig eth1 down
sudo ifconfig eth0 hw ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
sudo ifconfig eth1 hw ether yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
sudo ifconfig eth1 up

Hmm. ifconfig now reports the expected mac addresses but the IP addresses are still as they were. So I reboot...

And again, networking is broken (it is around this point that one learns the merit of editing /etc/init/failsafe.conf to shorten network delays during the networking debug process). The contents of /etc/network/interfaces are unchanged from how they look above. ifconfig now reports that eth0 and eth1 have the same (NAT adapter MAC) address even though I really did swap the MAC addresses above. Restore the MACs per the same procedure and reboot and we're back where we started (eth0 = host-only and eth1 = NAT).

**Therefore, the main question is: how do you swap eth0 and eth1 correctly on Ubuntu 13.10?** On CentOS (given DHCP) it was as easy as swapping the MAC addresses in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 and ifcfg-eth1 and then rebooting. On Ubuntu *it's like pulling teeth*... everything that should work won't work, and I am stumped. I suspect there's something relatively new going on under the hood (thus the "missing" rules files and so on) but what could it be? Note that the network-manager isn't installed by default either (and it's definitely not present).

---

**Update:** Just for grins I created another VM with the same default server setup (including OpenSSH as before), with one network adapter (NAT). No change - networking works as it normally would for this configuration, but there's nothing in /etc/udev/rules.d except a README file (I even checked as root... nothing).

Comment: Do you have /lib/udev/write_net_rules and /lib/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules ? They are in 13.04 as part of the udev pkg. They are what generate /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Yep, and I get the "missing $INTERFACE" error that's mentioned out there as well... it's rather frustrating.

Comment: You'll get that error from write_net_rules unless the proper environment vars are set. On my 13.04 system, 75-persistent-net-generator.rules sets those vars, and is run at boot time. I don't know what triggers it.

Comment: AHA! It's because this is a VM... I'll update my post or add an answer but now I know why that file wasn't getting generated.

Comment: Thank you again, @MarkPlotnick - you suggestions led me to examine that generator in detail, which led to my discovering the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I have at least a partial answer so far.

As I said, this is in a VM. The VM creates special MAC addresses of the form 08:00:27:xx:yy:zz. Along with several other scripts, I took a look at /lib/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules to see if the problem was in there. Turns out, that's one of several *excluded* address ranges specifically mentioned in that file (it tries to ignore virtual interfaces)!

So, to test that theory I commented out the line in that file, rebooted and presto! /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules gets generated with the MAC of the interface I currently have.

Next up: testing whether updating this alone and rebooting solves the problem. I'll update when I've gotten that tested.

**Update:** That was it! I removed the test fix and the generated file, shut down, added the second host-only network adapter and rebooted. The new adapter got enumerated first as eth0, and the NAT one then became eth1. I re-did the edit to the generator to remove the exclusion, rebooted and now I had a persistent rules file to work with.

In that file I simply swapped the device names (I changed NAME="eth0" to "eth1" and vice versa), saved, rebooted and voila - it worked!

Now, if you had entered MAC addresses elsewhere you'd want to correct those as well, but in this case it was very straightforward.